# MVC2 w/Areas Updated ChildApp.dll - Renders blank page/Error BC30456: 'Title' is not a member of

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have an MVC2 app using Areas. The app contains many child apps, each consisting of an MVC Child Application and a Child DataLayer class library (ChildApp1 and ChildApp1Data).  The MVC Child App, and the DataLayer class library DLL's are deployed into the Parent bin folder, and the views into the Parent Areas folder.  The app is deployed at client site and working great.

We have not had any problems delivering updated dll's for child apps until now.

We have now delivered an updated Child MVC App DLL and DataLayer dll (ChildApp1.dll, ChildApp1Data.dll) to the bin folder.  The views were not updated.

In this case the ChildApp1.dll was a newer compile, but the source DID NOT CHANGE.  Only the DataLayer was changed. (Support delivered the current pair together).

Now, when the Main.aspx page is rendered by the controller, the page is blank.  View source reveals the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML dpieagent_htmladvised="true"><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

Error BC30456: 'Title' is not a member of ... is logged.

The Main.aspx page starts with:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Main.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of SSManager.MainFormView)" %>
```

What could be causing this?

A search for "dpieagent_htmladvised" hasn't turned up any indication of what it is or where it came from.

After significant research, I have seen the cases where System.Data.Entity is an issue.  We do not use Entity anywhere.

I have seen the issues where the class name has caused problems.  The Class Name in SSManger was not changed, and the form view model MainFormView was not changed.

The environment is an IIS 6 webfarm, with F5 load balancer.

If I remove the strongly typed view model the page loads:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Main.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Any help/info would be greatly apppreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the SSManager complete namespace at the web.config system.web/pages/namespaces references?

Something like:

```
 <system.web>
     <pages>
         <namespaces>
            <add namespace="ChildApp1.SSManager"/>
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks Oleiro, but the DLL in question is a DataLayer module.  No classes from it are referenced in the view.  If we use classes in a view. (We typically use an Imports directive on the page anyway).  We have successfuly replaced DLL's in the bin folder for over a year.  This one has presented this unique error.